# Как перебрать класс в Java foreach

Tags: java

В Basic такой код создания пули

Тип пули

```
Type bullet
    Field x,y
End Type
```

Создать несколько экхемпляров:

```
for 1 to 10 
bullet.bullet = New bullet
 bullet\x=pd\x
 bullet\y=pd\y
EndIf
```

Отрисовка Пули:

```
For bullet.bullet = Each bullet
        bullet\x = bullet\x +10
        DrawImage  iBullet,bullet\x,bullet\y
        If bullet\x > 600 Then Delete bullet
Next
```

Есть `class One`:

```
public class One {
   int x;
   int y;
}
```

1) Работает ли этот код?

```
for (int i=1; i<5;i++) {
   One one = new One();
   One.x = 5*i;
}
```

2) Как перебрать его в `foreach`?

Comment: Не скомпилируется. `One.x` — это поле _какого_ экземпляра, по-вашему? Ну и оно у вас приватное, кстати.

Comment: Код не работает как минимум по двум причинам. А даже если работал бы, то скорее не так, как вы ожидаете

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста как как создать несколько классов и перебрать в forrech

Comment: @АлексейШиманский: http://coollib.com/i/49/146449/i_004.png

Comment: @ItsGonnaBeMe что вы подразумеваете под "перебрать класс в foreach" ?

Comment: Одну минутку. сейчас напишу

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно создать коллекцию объектов данного класса и заполнить ее объектами требуемого класса.

```
    List<One> ones = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        One one = new One();
        one.x = i * 5;
        ones.add(one);
    }
```

После чего, по этой коллекции можно проитерироваться и провести операции, которые вам нужны.

```
    for (One one : ones) {
        // что то там с one
    }
```

Comment: Сейчас протестирую

Comment: Спасибо все работает. Создаю свою модную игру на libgdx(Android).